# linux commandline impulse response convolution reverb

Tags: impulse-response

I need to do an ir convreverb on a lot of wav files i got, always with impulse responses of different rooms. it does not have to be zero latency so even calculating the convolutional reverb would be fine. I'm just searching for a possibility to do this from the commandline. Does anybody know a tool that can do what i'm searching for.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Jconvolver for that. It's a convolution reverb for JACK but it comes with a commandline utility called fconvolver. It takes some time setting up, but does the job nicely.

Answer (score -1):

You could do what you need with Matlab, or use Gnu Octave instead (Octave is free.)  Scipy would also be an alternative.

In any case, you will end up doing some coding to get what you want.  Whether you go with Matlab code, python code, or something else depends on your skills and programming experience.

[Matlab](http://www.mathworks.de/support/sysreq/current_release/index.html;jsessionid=a6bbef6ef3a124e7dc33191dd7a1?sec=linux) - commercial software.  I'm sure there is a download for a free demo on the site somewhere.

[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) - you can probably install this through your distributions package management.  You will also want to install the signal processing package through the Octave internal package management.  Octave code is nearly one to one compatible with Matlab, so any Matlab examples you find will mostly just work und Octave.

[Scipy](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) - you can probably install this through your distributions package management.

For Matlab and Octave, the function you need is [impulse](http://octave.sourceforge.net/control/function/impulse.html) - all you have to do is add the functionality for reading your files, using the impulse function, then writing the impulse response to another file.